# MySql- split cell and insert into another table

Tags: mysql, select, split, substring

I have a table **test** that has a column *state_numbers*

```
id  state_numbers
--  ------------
1  scr:1.0043;smb:0;rsm:0
2  scr:1.12;smb:0;rsm:0.3
3  scr:0.083;smb:0.65;rsm:0
4  scr:1.021;smb:0;rsm:0.2
5  scr:0.77;smb:0;rsm:0
```

I have created a table called **Status** that looks like

```
 id     scr    smb    rsm   total
------ ------ ------ ------ ------
(null) (null) (null) (null) (null)
```

I need a query that would read the value in *state_numbers*, split the expression based on the keyword and put the values in corresponding columns of Status table.

I'm expecting :

```
 id     scr    smb    rsm   total
------ ------ ------ ------ ------
1      1.0043   0      0    (null)
2      1.12     0     0.3   (null)
3      0.083   0.65    0    (null)
```

Then I will be able to add the data in each column and update in *total* column.

Final Output:

```
 id     scr    smb    rsm   total
------ ------ ------ ------ ------
1      1.0043   0      0    1.0043
2      1.12     0     0.3   1.42
3      0.083   0.65    0    0.733
```

How would I achieve this? help me in splitting the particular cell and inserting the data in different fields.

Thanks in advance!!!

P.S: pls suggest a proper title for this question

Comment: Hello, Jaywalker anti-pattern! Clear point is - if you have chosen such data model, then reconsider your application & DB architecture. If you can not do that (may be it's some legacy part) - then you should do that not in SQL, but in application - because in common case you'll not be able to resolve an issue only with SQL (sure, you can use stored SQL code - but, really, better to use application then)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, scr, smb, rsm, 
      (CAST(scr AS DECIMAL(18, 5)) + CAST(smb AS DECIMAL(18, 5)) + CAST(rsm AS DECIMAL(18, 5))) total
FROM (SELECT id, REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(state_numbers, ';', 1), 'scr:', '') scr, 
             REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(state_numbers, ';', -2), ';', 1), 'smb:', '') smb, 
             REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(state_numbers, ';', -1), 'rsm:', '') rsm
      FROM test
     ) AS A
```

Comment: I tried using your query and I get same values in all records

Comment: @damseldeebi Check my updated query. I had passed static value instead of column name. Now I had corrected it

Comment: it worked perfectly fine!! thanks a ton... I was able to store the result of the query in another table too...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MySQL split function by Federico Cargnelutti.](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/)

## Function by Federico Cargnelutti :

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

## Your sql:

```
select id,
    scr,
    smb,
    rsm,
    cast(scr as DECIMAL(10,5))+cast(rsm as DECIMAL(10,5))+cast(smb as DECIMAL(10,5)) as     total 
from (
    select 
    id,
    trim(replace(SPLIT_STR(state_numbers, ';', 1),'scr:','')) as scr,
    trim(replace(SPLIT_STR(state_numbers, ';', 2),'smb:','')) as smb,
    trim(replace(SPLIT_STR(state_numbers, ';', 3),'rsm:','')) as rsm 
from test) as myTable;
```